# How can i play a local video file on embedded windows media player control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know you can use url:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = 
    @"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=95772";
```

But if i want to play a local video file from my hard disk ?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/844451/Audio-and-Video-Player-Csharp-Winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL` doesn't necessarily needs an internet address. You can set it to a local address in your hard disk. Something like this:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\myvideo.avi";
```